# How to disable advance filtering in ag grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In v20 of Ag-grid(Angular 7), how can we disable advance filtering(like And and OR filtering)?

I tried using:

```
filterParams: {
    suppressAndOrCondition: true
}
```

But nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this through default column config :

**component.ts**

```
import { GridOptions, ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
...
gridOptions : GridOptions = {} ;

constructor(){

this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = { filterParams: {
      suppressAndOrCondition: true  }} ;

}
...
```

**html**

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Hi, It works in ag-grid community. But how to disable it in ag-grid enterprise?